# FastApi pydantic how to validate email

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am using pydantic to validate response I need to validate email. I am trying like this.

```
class CheckLoginRequest(BaseModel):
    user_email: str = Field(min_length=5,  default="username")
    user_number: str = Field(min_length=5, default="+923323789263")

    @field_validator("user_email")
    def validate_email(self, value):
        try:
            validate_email(value)
        except EmailNotValidError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid email format")
        return value
```

but Its showing error `pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: @field_validator cannot be applied to instance methods`

I try with `@validator` its working but its deprecated.

Comment: Do what it is saying. You have to use classmethod signature. Well explained in the docs. Btw, you have an infinite loop with your recursive call.

Comment: In general there is no need to implement email validation yourself, Pydantic has built-in (well, through `email-validator`) support for defining a field as an email address. Validation will then be performed on that field automagically: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/string_types/#emailstr - define your field as `EmailStr` to use the field type.

Answer (score 7):

The most modern and documented way, afaict, should be using the [`EmailStr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/networks/#pydantic.networks.EmailStr) type as documented e.g. [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/#customizing-json-schema).

```
from pydantic import EmailStr, Field

class UserBaseSchema(BaseModel):
    """User base schema."""
    email: EmailStr | None = Field(default=None)
```

It also beautifully integrates with other FastApi features such as docs and other tools in the ecosystem.

**NOTE:** It needs [email-validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) installed.

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to be a class method:

```py
class CheckLoginRequest(BaseModel):
    user_email: str = Field(min_length=5,  default="username")
    user_number: str = Field(min_length=5, default="+923323789263")

    @field_validator("user_email")
    @classmethod
    def validate_email(cls, value):
        try:
            validate_email(value)
        except EmailNotValidError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid email format")
        return value
```

The [doc](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#field-validators) provides more information.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a recursive call here - the `validate_email` function can be imported from somewhere else, as it doesn't reference `self` in OPs code (or `cls` in your code)?

Comment: with this its showing this This decorator will not receive a callable it may expect; the built-in decorator returns a special object  on field_validator

Comment: @MatsLindh you're correct, `validate_email()` references something else. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: @rameezkhan, I cannot reproduce your error. The code works fine for `r = CheckLoginRequest(user_email='foo@bar.baz', user_number='12345')` and it raises the exceptions when `'foo'` is passed as `user_email`. Please provide the version of pydantic and python, and details on how to reproduce your error.

Comment: Or try the solution proposed by @MatsLindh. It's almost always better to use an existing solution than to build one's own.